# I'm unable to generate the report in jenkins for the maven project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin, owasp, jenkins-cli

When I set goal 'install package dependency-check:check goal' it should generate a report (as I have installed html report plugin and dependency check plugin).
I'm running the build successfully but the report generation is failed. I'm getting the following error.  I tried to install all report plugin but it's of no use. How to generate report for my maven project?

> Directory exists but failed copying to.
>   This is especially strange since your build otherwise succeeded.

[image: error]

Comment: not much info in the link u provided..@SVMadhavaReddy

Comment: There is no info. But question is duplicate. That's what i've flagged.

Comment: but there is no proper solution found.. can i have a solution? @SVMadhavaReddy

Comment: what is your configuration??? job ??

Comment: @Hithesh once you have enough reputation, you'll be able to add bounties to questions to get solutions.